# In the Skobbler API, what unit is Annotation.setOffset() in

Tags: android, skmaps

When setting a custom image for the map markers (Annotations) on a Skobbler map, one can set the offset of the image using `SKAnnotation.seOffset(SKScreenPoint)`, so that the marker can line up proprly with the exact location of gps coordinates, but the documentation is not clear on what the unit of measurement is for `SKScreenPoint` or how the offset is calculated.

Is the offset in dip, px, or something else.

Is there a built in way to handle different screen densities using, or do I need to calculate the value based on screen density?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Offset in px.
For example, to set anchor point from center to bottom of annotation offset should be half of height:

```
annotation.setOffset(new SKScreenPoint(0 /*x*/, annotation_height/2 /*y*/));
```